# WordPress responsive menu does not hide links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi this is my website http://elisse.com.au/ if you test it mobile you will see that the links are always shown without clicking on the responsive menu button. i want it like when some clicks on the menu button then it displays

Comment: You are not hiding the ul element on smaller resolutions. It should be hidden by default (mobile first, from smaller to higher resolutions), so it can be displayed block when clicking the trigger. Then on min-width required for it to display expanded (inline or floated menu items) you should have display: block; There are other problems in there as well, like displaying 2 burger-icons. Gives me the impressions there are more things to look out for in order to make it work. That's why I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: i am still not sure. can you post it as answer so i can give it try

Answer (score 0):

You have a plugin that is conflicting with your theme.  Try disabling the js composer plugin.  Also, this question is not an appropriate one for stackoverflow and will almost certainly get closed.